# Как конвертировать строку в числовую константу?

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток!

Для использования переменной в enum встала необходимость перевода ее в константу,
в связи с чем столкнулся со следующим:

```
  public const int Aries = Convert.ToInt32(@"Sample text");
  Error 1 The expression being assigned to 'myNameSpace.Class2.Aries' must be constant
```

Есть ли адекватный способ перевода текста в int константу?

Comment: Что вы делаете?? Каким образом вы хотите превратить Sample text в int? Даже я не знаю как это сделать, а вы хотите это от компьютера!

Comment: Что же вы так - сумма кодов символов подойдет.

Comment: C# по умолчанию не умеет такого вида строки конвертировать. Сообщение выше подразумевало это. Если хотите осуществить конвертацию по своей особой логике, то тут уже все за вами. Реализуйте ту логику, которая устраивает именно вас.

Comment: 1. Это смотря что вы называете адекватным способом.
2. `const`-переменную нельзя инициализировать результатом вызова функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понял, в чём у Вас беда, - константа должна быть константой и вычисляться на этапе компиляции, а не в ран тайме. Соответсвенно - просто поставить не строку :-) Потому что функция не может быть вычислена на этапе компиляции, будь то Convert.toInt[16|32|64], int.Parse или что ещё.

Comment: Благодарю за совет!

Answer (score 1):

Если значение константы невозможно вычислить на этапе компиляции, то вместо `const` можно использовать `static readonly`:

```
public static readonly int Aries = Convert.ToInt32(@"Sample text");
```